# How do I invoke a collection of Generic Predicates?

Tags: c#

**My Setup**

I have an Entity class that stores a collection of Components:

```
public class Entity
{
    public Dictionary<Type, IComponent> Components { get; set; }
}
```

Components are any class that implement IComponent and for example are things like Position, Orientation etc.

I have a Filter class that stores a collection of Conditions which are basically just predicates:

```
public class Filter
{
    public Dictionary<Type, MulticastDelegate> Conditions;

    public Filter()
    {
        Conditions = new Dictionary<Type, MulticastDelegate>();
    }

    public void Add<T>(Predicate<T> predicate) where T : class, IComponent
    {
        Conditions.Add(typeof(T), predicate);
    }
}
```

**My Problem**

What I am trying to do is allow for the creation of a filter that has different conditions (predicates) for different components. I want to write a method that returns true for any Entity whose Components all match the conditions.

**What I have so far**

```
public bool IsMatchFor(Entity entity)
{
    foreach (IComponent component in entity.Components.Values)
    {
        if (Conditions.ContainsKey(component.GetType()))
        // There is a both a Condition in the Filter and a Component in the Entity that match up based on Type. 
        // Now check to see if the Condition is satisfied by the Component
        {
            Type genericPredicate = typeof(Predicate<>);
            Type[] typeArgs = { component.GetType() };
            Type constructedGenericPredicate = genericPredicate.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
            Predicate<IComponent> predicateInstance = (Predicate<IComponent>)Activator.CreateInstance(constructedGenericPredicate, new object[] { component, Conditions[component.GetType()].Method });

            if (!predicateInstance.Invoke(component))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

**The Error I get**

However I get an error. Basically I cannot seem to construct the necessary Predicate. Is there an easier way to do this?

```
Test method Tests.Utilities.FilterTests.IsMatchFor_WithASingleConditionThatMatchesEntity_ReturnsTrue threw exception: 
System.MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'System.Predicate`1[[Tests.TestSupportClasses.ComponentType1, Tests, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' not found.
Result StackTrace:  
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
   at Entropy.Utilities.Filter.IsMatchFor(Entity entity) in c:\git\Entropy\Source\Utilities\Filter.cs:line 54
   at Tests.Utilities.FilterTests.IsMatchFor_WithASingleConditionThatMatchesEntity_ReturnsTrue() in c:\git\Entropy\Tests\Utilities\FilterTests.cs:line 128
```

**One Use Case to show why this is more complicated than it seems**

I want to be able to write the following code:

```
_filter.Add(typeof(ComponentType1), (Predicate<IComponent>)(new Predicate<ComponentType1>(c => c.BoolProperty)));
Assert.IsTrue(_filter.IsMatchFor(_entities[0]));
```

Basically by using a generic Predicate, I am able to get the editor to help me create a condition. However the above line will fail at compile time, since Predicate(Of IComponent) is not inherited from Predicate(Of ComponentType1) even though ComponentType1 implements IComponent.

Comment: You're trying to create a `Predicate<T>` which doesn't exist in the actual type implementation of `IComponent`. Is there any reason you're not retrieving the predicate from the `Conditions` dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you actually need is a `Dictionary<Type, Predicate<IComponent>>` rather than a general one which holds a `MulticastDelegate`:

```
public Dictionary<Type, Predicate<IComponent>> Conditions;
```

When declared that way, you don't need to use reflection at all and can simply retrieve the `Predicate<IComponent>` from the dictionary rather easily:

```
public bool IsMatchFor(Entity entity)
{
    foreach (IComponent component in entity.Components.Values)
    {
        Predicate<IComponent> componentPredicate;
        if (Conditions.TryGetValue(component.GetType(), out componentPredicate))
        {
            return componentPredicate(component);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I've added a Use Case to show why I went through all that trouble. Basically, I need to have a base class for storing different generic Predicate types together.